# Prevent automated robots submitting forms to ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bots, simple-form, spam

What would be a good decent way to fix a form that is submitted everyday numerous times by robots posting all kind of rubbish through it?

I have this beta signup form with a hidden field and a username and password field.
This get's submitted numerous times a day and results in error reports in my rails application.

Is there a decent ruby on rails way to prevent robots submitting my forms?
I know you can do all kind of stuff in the frontend but most tricks seem to fail ( im using a hidden field trick to check for robots, still they pass there mess true )

**EDIT #1:**

Adding the form data posted by automated robot. 
It seems its posting extra form fields even when they are not present in the form.

> - URL       : http://mysite.com/beta  * IP address: 91.121.170.197  * Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>     "authenticity_token"=>"8mvHnQgX0krwnymdOeQgd8AP52H/ZrJKjnKcUBGrcMM=",
>     "betum"=>{"code"=>""}, "name"=>"Bryan", "email"=>"quaker@yahoo.com",
>     "commit"=>"Joignez-vous Â»", "comment"=>"I need to charge up my phone
>     http://pposchool.com/classes/ \">desirel 50  provided
>     that no more than two of the rotations are involved in non-patient
>     care\n http://sdccpa.com/professionals \">Proventil Hfa
>     Inhaler Cost  Goal 6: Promote public health and disease
>     prevention.\n http://hunterdk.com/products-2/ \">cost
>     clomid treatment uk  12. Displays effective nonverbal behaviors
>     (eye contact, body language,\n ", "action"=>"create",
>     "controller"=>"beta"}  * Rails root: /srv/myapp/current  * Timestamp
>     : 2013-09-03 17:34:10 +0200

Comment: its not true.. its through

Comment: Fix your app! (if this causes errors) It's not the first time you're asking a really strange question and I start wondering what are you doing out there!

Comment: I do basic form input validation in my code but still fails. Your right I could add better form value validation to my code for example limit the names to 12 chars and already checking for the email format if its correct. Although the data *still* gets posted thats the problem not sure how they do it I post some error log to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [captcha](http://www.captcha.net/) in the form.

Have a look at this [simple catcha gem](https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha).

Comment: I wanted no captcha, not mentioned that in my question though. Although there seems no real other solution perhaps to prevent form submits without it.

Comment: This one seems not rails 4 compatible, could be made compatible but something that works out of the box would be preferable if I should go this way, it -is- a solution but not the way I want to go just yet.

Comment: I won't be adding one but seems best solution. I leave it as is for now and later on look into adding captcha to my beta signup form. Its a cosmetic whitedrawel

Answer (score 2):

Hard to understand very last part of your question...I'm wondering whether the hidden field is getting filled in by robots or it's being left blank (as it would by a real user).

If it's consistently being filled in then why not just reject any form that contains a value in that hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

Captcha is heavy hammer and should be a last resort. It f's up your UX. If robots.txt doesn't work, blacklist the IP(s) using [Rack Attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack). Rack attack offers all kinds of cool ways to filter nuisance traffic, rate limit, etc.